# $wpdb query and the changing prefix

Tags: mysql, wordpress

So I am building a nice little plugin for myself. The database is working fine . I have made the table using the $wpdb->prefix and it has happily come out with wp_my_table.

So when I upload it to a live site for testing, as it has the database prefix changed, the plugin no longer works with the database.

My $wpdb query only seems to work with `SELECT * FROM wp_my_table ORDER desc`when I manually adjust this to the new database prefix xxxwp_my_table. How do I get my plugin to auto adjust to the changed table?

I have tried various ‘$wpdb->my_table’ or other such things but they just don’t quite make sense.
Anyone with a heads up on this?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Are you saying `$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}my_table ORDER desc" );` isn't working?

Comment: Can you take your time to rephrase comprehensibly your question? As it stands, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Hi, Sorry if I wasn't quite clear. I was quite tired after searching for a solution for some time. I have managed to find the solution now. My issue was that I had missed `$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'table_name';`  and hence my prefix wasn't added automatically. ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Database_Table_Prefix  and https://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-the-table-prefix-from-wp-configphp-and-upgrade-with-the-same-prefix/